# Can I connect Forms 6i and 10g both with database 11g at a time?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to connect Forms 6i with database 11g R2 but currently I am using Forms 10g with database 11g R2. I want to use both of these Forms. Can I connect Oracle Forms 6i and 10g with database 11g R2 both at a time? What is the solution?

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you mean you want to have **one application** running a mix of Forms10g and Forms6i? If so, why? Are you trying to use Forms6i in client/server mode? Or do you just want to have two different applications connecting to the same database?

Comment: Why would you want to connect 6i if you have Forms 10g? Just open your 6i forms in 10g forms and make necessary changes if needed. Most of 6i forms will compile in 10g w/out any modifications/upgrades, etc...

Comment: I have two different applications want to connect to same database 11g R2

Answer (score 0):

- You didn't mention which operating system you use. If it is a modern MS Windows, note that Forms 6i is an old piece of software which was never certified nor supported on Windows 10 (nor Windows 7). Although I've read that people managed to install it and made it work, there's no guarantee that you'll manage to do it as well. You'll have to Google a lot and read a lot, collect pieces of knowledge and hope for the best.
- when you installed all those Oracle products onto your computer, you should have installed each of them into its own Oracle Home (i.e. directory); otherwise, you can expect problems (such as files being overwritten).
- as each Forms installation uses its own TNSNAMES.ORA, both of them should contain an entry for your Oracle 11g database. If not, Forms that doesn't have it will fail to connect. Alternatively (which is what I'd suggest) is to create a TNS_ADMIN environment variable which points to a directory which will contain a single copy of the TNSNAMES.ORA file (for example, C:\ORALIB) - doing so, you'd have to maintain only one copy of the file, instead of two (or even more) of them .
- apart from that, you should be able to run both Forms versions. What happened when you tried to run Forms 6i? Do you get any error? If so, which one?